# CSS layout with a fixed center div surrounded by equally sized fluid divs

Tags: css, layout, width

For a graphic effect, I'm attempting to create a div with a specific width (800 or 1000 px) surrounded by 2 equally sized fluid divs.

The left div is green, the middle div is white and contains a left-aligned logo image that starts with the same green, and the right div is white. The middle div should always be centered.

Is there a good way to do this using CSS? Otherwise, what other clean looking and browser-friendly approaches are there?

Edit(x2) my current test file:

This works, but the right div overlaps the center div, and I'd prefer if the left and right divs were exactly the remaining width instead of going under the center div (in case I would like to do a similar thing later)

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
  .header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 60px;
    background-color: grey;
  }
  .headercontents {
    width: 800px;
    height: 60px;
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: red;
    float: left;
    z-index: 99;
  }
  .left {
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: green;
    height: 60px;
    width: 49%;
    margin-right: -400px;
    float: left;
    z-index: 1;
  }
  .right {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 60px;
    background-color: blue;
    width: 49%;
    margin-left: -800px;
    float: right;
    z-index: 1;
  }
</style>
<div class="header">
  <div class="left"></div>
  <div class="headercontents"></div>
  <div class="right"></div>
</div>
```

Code functioning perfectly with JavaScript:

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
  BODY {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
  }
  .header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 60px;
    background-color: grey;
  }
  .headercontents {
    width: 800px;
    height: 60px;
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: red;
    z-index: 99;
  }
  .left {
    height: 60px;
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: green;
    z-index: 1;
  }
  .right {
    height: 60px;
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: blue;
    z-index: 1;
  }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="header">
  <div class="left edge"></div><!--
  --><div class="headercontents"></div><!--
  --><div class="right edge"></div>
</div>
<script>
var leftEle = document.body.querySelector(".left");
var rightEle = document.body.querySelector(".right");

window.onresize = function() {
    var width = window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth;
    if (width > 800) {
      var lrWidth = width / 2 - 400;
      leftEle.style.display = 'inline-block';
      rightEle.style.display = 'inline-block';
      leftEle.style.width = lrWidth;
      rightEle.style.width = lrWidth;
    } else {
      leftEle.style.display = 'none';
      rightEle.style.display = 'none';
      // It would be nice to scroll the page horizontally to the center here
    }
}
window.onload = window.onresize;
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you show your code?

Comment: I've put a temporary header after many failed attempts, so I don't have the code I was testing with anymore. I attempted floating the middle and right divs (all combinations of left and right), but I couldn't get the desired effect that way.
Here's some skeleton code though:
`<div class="header">
<div class="left"></div>
<div class="headercontents"></div>
<div class="right"></div>
</div>
.headercontents {
width: 800px;
}
.left {
/* width is screen size - 800 / 2 */
}
.right {
/* width is equal to left */
}`
Also, during my testing I had the divs set as inline-blocks.

Comment: please add your code to the question ...

Comment: Good call. It's up there now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your best off using javascript for that specific effect. Floats and inline-block fill according to content if width isn't given.

```
var leftEle = document.body.querySelector(".left");
var rightEle = document.body.querySelector(".right");


window.onresize = function() {
    var width = window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth;
    var lrWidth = width / 2;
    leftEle.style.width = lrWidth;
    rightEle.style.width = lrWidth
}
```

I would probably try to use a mix of fluid design (using percentages on layout) with media queries to get the document to look right at different screen sizes.

Comment: JavaScript is what I intend on doing if I can't get the CSS working (which seems likely). I'd use onresize for that though, since I don't want to depend on the initial size of the users window.

Comment: Really, unless you have to have that layout, I would look at using media queries.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe if you use `float:left` and `display:inline-block` on each `div`.  See how that works.

Comment: I tried that, and just wrote a new html file to test it again. It results in the left and right divs both having a width of 0.

Comment: You'd have to add content to them, set a `min-width`, or try to give them *all* `width:33%` (and get rid of the `float` property).  It's not perfect if you have OCD unless you wunna try `33.333333333333333333333%` XD

Comment: Unfortunately a width of 33% wouldn't work (I agree though; that's quite OCD inducing). The center div, rather than being a third of the screen width, has to maintain a fixed size so it can fit (and fit to) all the controls inside.

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a wrapper and nesting the 3 divs inside.

For example:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div id="leftDiv"> div content </div>
    <div id="centerDiv"> div content </div>
    <div id="rightDiv"> div content </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That's essentially the layout I had.

Answer (score 0):

The cleanest and less problematic way is comment out the space between the child elements in your html code and use the property `display: inline-block` on the child elements so they... well display inline without breaking the layout:

```
<div class="billboard grid">
    <div class="grid__item"></div><!--
    --><div class="grid__item"></div><!--
    --><div class="grid__item"></div>
</div>
```

Then use the css `:nth-child(n)` psudo-selector to manually set the properties according to your needs

```
.grid {
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 4rem;
}

.grid__item{
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100%;


}
.grid .grid__item:nth-child(1) {
    background: color;
    width: 10%
}

.grid .grid__item:nth-child(2) {
    background: color;
    width: 80%
}
.grid .grid__item:nth-child(3) {
    background: color;
    width: 10%
}
```

Here is an view for this [example](http://jsfiddle.net/x7Y6r/).

Comment: Thats good advice if he's having issues with using inline block. The problem he is having is that he want's dynamic and static width columns.